Vue3 Typescript Sum all values of a column in an array
I'm still very new to this programming language and I'm trying to take an array column and sum its values so I can show a total amount on the webpage.
Question #1
I was attempting to use a computed property as I see that's the standard way of doing this type of calculation in vue3 so its not recalculated each time the webpage is refreshed but I've also read that breaking it down into a for each loop is way more efficient by a large margin, which is the best method?.
Questions #2
Depending on which method is best how would I code this?
I can't find many examples online of what I'm trying to achieve, I have seen some use Array.Reduce() but when I use this it doesn't ever produce a result and I'm not sure how I can troubleshoot that to find if its something I did wrong or this method just won't work for my use case.
This is roughly the array formatting, the Total_Tax1 and Grand_Total I'd like to calculate separately in their own variables.
{
"current_page":1,
"data":
[
 {
  "id":1,
  "Invoice_Number":1,
  "Total_Price":"10.00",
  "Total_Tax1":"4.50",
  "Grand_Total":"14.50",
 }
 {
  "id":2,
  "Invoice_Number":2,
  "Total_Price":"10.00",
  "Total_Tax1":"2.50",
  "Grand_Total":"12.50",
 }
]
}


The question isn't specific enough, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . "that breaking it down into a for each loop" -  please, clarify what you mean, you'd have to use a loop inside of a computed, they aren't either one or another at all. "when I use this it doesn't ever produce a result " - what did you try? The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

I apologize I was having a hard time trying to explain myself, by breaking it down I just meant using a for each loop to iterate through the array, also thanks for the clarification on the computed. As I've tried and then deleted what I tried and tried another method, I don't have any examples but let me see if I can find what I was looking at before and reproduce them, I'll edit this question later this evening and clean it up.

In order to make your data reactive, you need to wrap it inside a Ref object. Assuming you have an API returning this data and you're calling it using Axios:
const pagination = ref(null);

The pagination is a reactive representation of your data. If you change it, other parts of the program will update themselves. Note that null is the initial value that you can set.
Here's how you can update it after calling the server:
axios.get('/some-endpoint')
   .then(({data}) => pagination.value = data);

Now you can easily define your computed properties to calculate the sums like this:
const sumTotalTax1 = computed(() =>
  pagination.value
    ? pagination.value.data.reduce(
        (sum, val) => sum + Number(val.Total_Tax1),
        0
      )
    : 0
);

const sumGrandTotal = computed(() =>
  pagination.value
    ? pagination.value.data.reduce(
        (sum, val) => sum + Number(val.Grand_Total),
        0
      )
    : 0
);

You can then use their values like this:
console.log(sumTotalTax1.value);
console.log(sumGrandTotal.value);

